# Select data from Json array using php

Tags: php, arrays, json, select

I know I'm not the only one asking this question, and the answer might be really simple.
But I couldn't find the answer for my specific question in other questions, so;

I have this Json data;

```
$house = [ 
 { 
   "ID": "1", 
   "NAME": "Test" 
 }, 
 { 
   "ID": "3", 
   "NAME": "Office" 
 } 
]
```

And I would like to know how I can select the ID numbers of all the rooms in $house.
So I would like `$room_numbers = [1,3];`
I thought I could select '1' with something like;

```
echo $house[0][0]
```

but that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `json_decode()`  [docs json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
    <?php


    $result = '[{  "ID": "1",  "NAME": "Test" }, { "ID": "3", "NAME": "Office" }]';

    $ARRAY = json_decode($result,true);

    //second parameter true is used to decode as a array 
    //print_r($ARRAY);

   echo $ARRAY[0]["ID"];

    ?>
```

**OUTPUT:**      1

For getting both ids loop the array like this

**Method 1:**

```
foreach($ARRAY as $key=>$val)
{
   $room_numbers[]=$val['ID'];
 }

 print_r($room_numbers);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  array(1,3);
```

**Method 2:**

use `array_column` to Get column of ID from a recordset

```
     $new_array=  array_column($ARRAY,'ID');

     print_r($new_array);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
        array(1,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$house = json_decode($house);
echo $house[0]->ID;
```

You can loop and print both ids,

```
$house = json_decode($house);
foreach($house as $row){
    echo $row->ID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'array_map' function for this, here is an example:

```
$house = '[ 
 { 
   "ID": "1", 
   "NAME": "Test" 
 }, 
 { 
   "ID": "3", 
   "NAME": "Office" 
 } 
]';

$house = json_decode($house, true);

$result = array_map(function($item) {
    if (isset($item['ID'])) {
        return $item['ID'];
    }
}, $house);

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with for loop

```
//this variable should be valid JSON string
$house = '[ 
 { 
   "ID": "1", 
   "NAME": "Test" 
 }, 
 { 
   "ID": "3", 
   "NAME": "Office" 
 } 
]';

$house = json_decode($house, true);
$room_numbers = array();
for( $i = 0; $i < count($house); $i++ ){
$room_numbers[] = $house[$i]["ID"];
}

//echo var_dump($room_numbers);
//echo json_encode($room_numbers);
```

Example with while loop

```
//this variable should be valid JSON string
$house = '[ 
 { 
   "ID": "1", 
   "NAME": "Test" 
 }, 
 { 
   "ID": "3", 
   "NAME": "Office" 
 } 
]';

$house = json_decode($house, true);
$room_numbers = array();
$i = 0
while($i < count($house)) {
$room_numbers[] = $house[$i]["ID"];
$i++;
}

//echo var_dump($room_numbers);
//echo json_encode($room_numbers);
```